# Android how to request action or approval from another user - concept

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a feature on my android/firebase(cloud firestore) app that requires another user's approval/denial. For example, when a user on Air&BnB wants to book a place and the owner has to approve or deny the request.

I've been looking around for a couple of days for answers or suggestions on how to do this but I haven't found any examples I can go off of. Perhaps I'm overthinking this.

So far, I've looked at push notifications although no examples show you how to send it to another user, unfortunately. They either show you how to send yourself one or how to send it to your users from Firebase to promote user engagement. I get the sense that this is not the right way to go about it.

I'm looking for any direction or guidance on how to do this. All help is appreciated.

If your choice is downvote, please give a reason why.

Thanks in advance.

**update**

I thought about it more and drew this up. If anyone has a better approach, im all ears.

[image]

Comment: Can't you simply save the firebase token of each user in firestore and send them the notification individually with that token whenever you need?

Comment: Any solution for this? I am working on the similar concept where one user is requesting another user with Allow and Deny options

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the use of a listener, you can create a notification from the listener.

When you change the user document the listener will go off.

for example:

```
documentReferenceUser.addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshot, e) -> {
                    assert documentSnapshot != null;
                    CloudUser cloudUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(CloudUser.class);
                    assert cloudUser != null;
                    if(cloudUser.hasRequests()){
                        // create the notification here.
                    }
                });
```